# syntax error on main{} bracket, "expected while"?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, do-while

I am completely stumped. No matter what I do it my compiler thinks I need a while loop at my last printf? It just keeps asking for things that don't make sense. When I add them in it just tells me that it shouldn't be there, and when I remove it i'm told I need it.

```
int main() {
float userInput; //The grades that the user inputs.
int passingGrade = 0; //Number of passing grades
int failingGrade = 0; //Failing grades
int invalidGrade = 0; //Invalid grades

//This do for loop is simply counting the number of grades of each catagory posted.
do {
    printf("Enter a grade (Enter -1 to quit):");
    scanf("%f", &userInput);
    printf("You entered: %.1f\n", userInput);
    if ((userInput > 100) || (userInput < 0)) { //Over 100 is impossible.
        invalidGrade = invalidGrade + 1;
        printf("You input an impossible grade!\n");
    }
    else {
        if (userInput > 70) { //Greater than 70 means passing.
            passingGrade = passingGrade + 1;
        }
        else {
            if ((userInput < 70) && !(userInput < 0)) {
                failingGrade = failingGrade + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (userInput != -1);
}
    printf("You entered %i passing grades.\n", passingGrade);
    printf("You entered %i failing grades.\n", failingGrade);
    printf("You entered %i invalid grades.\n", invalidGrade);
    system("pause"); }
```

The code runs just fine, and does everything I expect it to do. But the compiler seems to think that there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Why `system("pause")` instead of using `pause()` directly?

Comment: This sort of problem is much easier to figure out yourself if you learn to properly indent your code so that you can follow the flow of execution. And when it comes to syntax, the compiler knows exactly what is wrong; it doesn't *think* there's a problem.

Comment: pause() seems to catch compiler errors. I'm not sure why, but it is probably because of how everything is made to be set up in my course. Otherwise i'd be using the easier version.

Comment: @paul Your "formatting" edit fixed the do/while syntax error thus making the posted answer incorrect and confusing. Please don't fix errors when you're just doing code formatting.

Comment: @Blastfurnace My bad. I will watch out next time. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your while loop is inside the do statement.
If you are doing

```
do while
```

it should look like this:

```
do {

} while (...);
```

Comment: AH! Thank you. Sorry for asking such a dumb question, I honestly kept looking past it. I appreciate you pointing out the mess up, i'm still getting used to syntax and just made a huge fool of myself.

Comment: No problem! Good luck :)